# Microservices and authentication approach

Tags: authentication, microservices

I am coming today because I would like to make sure I have the right approach in terms of microservice architecture for a login/register/authentication approach.

I first thought I would have 2 services:

- API
- Users Service

I would have the authentication process shared between my API and my Users Service. I would, by example, login from my API by trying to find the combination username/password in the users service, then on success, generating a token and returning it to the user. API would then handle the authentication token (in Redis or others)

However, moving forward into microservices and loosely coupling approach, I saw that some people actually split the Authentication data from the user data (such as age, first name, phone number, etc...). So I now have the following approach:

- API (send the data to the authentication service. On success, it request addUser/getuserbyid of users service and then return the data)
- Authentication Service (hold users account information)
- Users Service (hold users information)

[image]

What's then the best approach? Because on fail, I don't know how can I manage.

Let's take the case where We can authenticate but the users service crashed because of another process. The user has a created account but no user profile. For that case, it makes everything harder..

Thanks for any interesting point of view :)

Comment: What is the business impact of failure? I mean, if the authentication data is successfully stored, then the user can login and fill in the missing profile info any time. The probability of failing is pretty low generally. If your profile is critical to functioning, you can treat the user's state as "INCOMPLETE" till it does not fill the profile. You can emit an ProfileCompleted event that other services process and enable access to themselves for that user (eg. by building an ACL). With these, the "Users Service" should require authentication (e.g. JWT based).

Comment: It's an interesting approach, thanks for your comment. So, if a user registers and its profile isn't created (but its account did), the user then gets an error (failure). Next time the user registers or login, I should first check if the profile has been COMPLETELY registered. If not, I then continue the steps, am I right? (I mean following your approach for failure)

Comment: Yeah. We also solved it this way due to did not want to put business data in Keycloak - our Auth SRV. We check the user's status after every login, and if it returns sth like 'incomplete', we automatically complete the registration. (This is only required for us since we synch some of the registration data to other services, and since Keycloak does not support at-least-once delivery for custom event publisher plugins, we need to handle failure of synchronous calls and provide retries).

Comment: Generally, if you have some number of systems and there is a workflow that needs to modify data in each of them "transactionally", you have to prepare for partial failures/incomplete state and retries. Or implement Sagas :)

Comment: I actually thought about a transactional approach but.. across services... To me, it seems to be a bad approach I don't know :( A flag system can be good, retry system can be even better. As you said, it should not fail, but if it does then... I thought also I could remove the created entry but if it fails, same issue. I think the flag approach it's my best way for now, now I have to hopefully having it work because otherwise, a profile can stays as IMCOMPLETED ahah